# Can you trade treasure boxes with other players?

Tags: dota-2

I heard you can trade all kind of items with other players in dota 2. I haven't had a chance to check what and how can you do that, so here's a question:

Can players trade the treasure boxes they get as well? And if it's possible to trade them, do people usually want to trade things for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can trade treasure boxes.

In fact I give mine away all the time (no, seriously!). I figure the 2.5 USD is better spent in real life, and if someone wants those boxes that bad, then they are more than welcome to have mine :).

Comment: Any idea are other players willing to trade other Dota 2 items for treasure boxes, or is TB's value in trading worthless?

Comment: TBs are traded, and the value is not worthless. In fact there is a subreddit on Dota2Trade. A quick google confirmed this, people are willing to exchange TBs in return for Treasure Keys (2 for 1) and even Dota2 Invites.

Comment: Alright then. Since i did ask in my original question do people usually want to trade things for them add that to your original answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can trade them, in the same way you would trade hats and the like in TF2.

You can also sell them, although they only sell for about 1 pence / cent at the best times.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/

Comment: Unless u keep some really old ones which gain a bit value after long time.